# Installed composer on new VM but it will not run

Tags: php, composer-php

I went to https://getcomposer.org/download/ and executed the top 4 lines to install composer. I now see composer.phar when I SSH into my server. I am trying to install Laravel and when I run composer global require "laravel/installer" I get the following:

-bash: composer: command not found

I have gone through the first 3 pages of Google and searched here. I run php composer.phar and can see all the commands as intended. I run:

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check

and get: All settings correct for using Composer

I installed this years ago on a different server but had to upgrade to php 7 so I got a new one. I don't remember this being such an issue back then. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably didn't move composer.phar to a [global installation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally)

Comment: That was it @GGG thanks

Comment: No problem. I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've forgotten to move your installation to a [global installation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally):

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```